# default sorting column and sort-icon in p-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, angular5

I have p-table structure like this. by default when page loads It should display a date column sorted along with sorticon in up arrow. (asc).When I click the column it happens. How to make the date column sorted on page load.

```
<p-table  [value]="dataOne" [responsive]="true" 
[columns]="cols" [first]="first"
(sortFunction)="ownSort($event)" [ownSort]="true" >
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
   <tr [class.tableSticky]="sticky">
      <th *ngFor="let value of data" [className]="value.field">
      <span >
         <p-sortIcon [field]="value.field"></p-sortIcon>
      </span>
      </th>
   </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-review>
   <tr> 
      <td *ngFor="let value of data" [ngClass]="{'menu' : value.field=='menu'}" [className]="value.field">
      </td>
   </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

ts:

```
 data = [
        { field: 'level', header: 'level' },
        { field: 'data1', header: 'data1' },
        { field: 'date', header: 'date' },
        { field: 'data3', header: 'data3' },
        ...
    ];
```

I tried but its not working:

`<p-table sortField="data.field=='date'" [sortOrder]="-1">`

actual UI:

[image]

Expected

[image]

Comment: Where are the dates coming from? your `data` array has no dates. Also, what is `dataOne`?